# i want to assign global variable into local varibale but i am getting error. ;expected

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
public string strSubCat = "";
strCategory += @"<li class='dropdown menu-large nav-item'><a href='# class='dropdown- 
                           toggle nav-link' data-toggle='dropdown'>" + dr["Category_name"] +@ </a>
                           <ul class='dropdown-menu megamenu'>
                           <div class='row'>
                            "string subcat1 = null;     
                                 subcat1 +=strSubCat + @"
                           </div>
                        </ul>
                    </li>";
```

Comment: It's very hard to understand what you're trying to do from the code, can you add more information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Miss some double quotes and ";"

Try this :  ?

```
     string strSubCat = "";
    strCategory += @"<li class='dropdown menu-large nav-item'><a href='# class='dropdown- 
                   toggle nav-link' data-toggle='dropdown'>" + dr["Category_name"] + @" </a>
                   <ul class='dropdown-menu megamenu'>
                   <div class='row'>;
                    ";
string subcat1 = null;
subcat1 +=strSubCat + @"
                   </div>
                </ul>
            </li>";
```

Comment: i want ot assign multiple values into local variable but i am getting error

Comment: i want to declare string variable but i am getting error , can any one help me